# why I am getting this output in djangorestframework-jwt

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

hello I have implemented JWT in my test project using this package "djangorestframework-jwt"

I have generated the token by giving my "username" and "password"

but the problem is that I am getting this output bypassing my token with the endpoint

I am using postman to test API,Django=2.2.12, python 3.7.6

I am not getting my data from the database[image]

{"eno":["This field is required."],"ename":["This field is required."],"esal":["This field is required."],"eaddr":["This field is required."]}

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not correct, but I try to explain you what happend. So,

You try send `POST` request to your `/api/` route and you got error because you dont send any `required data`. Go to `Body` tab and click on 'raw' radio button and than change 'Text' to JSON and insert correct JSON with data that you want to send to your server, it will be looks like:

```
{
 "eno": "your_eno",
 "ename": "your_ename"
 .....
}
```

You should read about it if you dont know.